# How to stub URL parameters with mockingjay

Tags: swift, mocking, stubbing

Does anyone know how to stub URL parameters with [mockingjay](https://github.com/kylef/Mockingjay) like the following:

```
https://backend.ch/comments?entry=KghNJZJeYYE5Lheb3
```

I tried to stub this request like this:

```
stub(http(.get, uri: "/comments?entry={id}"), jsonData(comments))
```

but this does not work. Am I doing something wrong or is mockingjay not capable of doing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no such option provided out of the box. However you can try to write your own matcher instead of using the default `http(_ method:uri)`.

You can try the solution someone posted as an issue [here](https://github.com/kylef/Mockingjay/issues/61)